# Make original site url name to some fake url name

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, webserver

I am new to rewrite site url name. I have a site url like `http://66.15.101.250/test/` . this is my owned server link  So i want to change this site url to something other name like  `http://testsite/test/` ( i do not want to give domain name to this ip address url).And i have otheres site running on this `http://66.15.101.250/test/` server . I have no idea how to do this, what should i do.

Is this possible through .htaccess file or something else

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server can only respond to requests it receives, and will only receive requests routed to it by DNS, so if you don't own the domain name, you can't receive public traffic directed towards it. You could silently redirect users from 
`http://66.15.101.250/test/` to the content found at `http://testsite/test/` but they would still see the `http://66.15.101.250/test/` url in their browser.

If you think about it, its a good thing you can't do this or I could make **stealyourcreditcardinfo.com** appear as **paypal.com**. Indeed most uses for what you are asking about would not be legitimate ones...

For your own internal testing purposes, you can make virtual host entry for testsite.com and your server will respond to any requests it receives for testsite.com. You then change your HOSTS file to point testsite.com to 127.0.0.1 and testsite.com will work in your browser, but only on your machine because you manually overrode your own DNS. The DNS everyone else is using is still pointing testsite.com to the actual IP address somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for testing purposes (as it seems to me), you can put `66.15.101.250 testsite` in your [`hosts` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) and configure a virtual host for `testsite` in your webserver.